# Aegir - Debian PGP key has expired

Tags: aegir

I am trying to Install aegir on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 lts to manage drupal sites.
Every time I try to update the server and  install aegir it displays the following error
me@userpc:# apt-get update

Hit:1 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease

Get:2 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]

Get:3 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [83.3 kB]

Get:5 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]

Get:4 http://debian.aegirproject.org stable InRelease [3,144 B]

Err:4 http://debian.aegirproject.org stable InRelease

The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 5ADF93A03376CCF9 Aegir Debian archive autosigning debian@debian.aegirproject.org
Reading package lists... Done

W: GPG error: http://debian.aegirproject.org stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 5ADF93A03376CCF9 Aegir Debian archive autosigning debian@debian.aegirproject.org
E: The repository 'http://debian.aegirproject.org stable InRelease' is not signed.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I tried to Get the renewed key using the following command but it doesn't seem to work ...

curl http://debian.aegirproject.org/key.asc | sudo apt-key add

sudo apt-get update

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Aegir 3 is minimally-maintained. Vendors offering support are Omega8, Consensus, ThinkDrop, and Symbiotic (who maintains some components at https://github.com/coopsymbiotic). Find them all at https://docs.aegirproject.org/community/services/.

For on-going support (as Debian packages are no longer maintained):

- Install from Git, and follow the 7.x-3.x branches, or
- Use Consensus'
  Ansible roles (https://gitlab.com/consensus.enterprises/ansible-roles/)
- Migrate to the BOA fork (https://github.com/omega8cc/boa), which will continue as an Aegir 3 LTS initiative. Please see their issue queue (and create a migration ticket for this if there isn't one already).
- Migrate to OpenDevShop (https://github.com/opendevshop/devshop).
  DevShop will continue to develop & support the Hosting modules in the
  4.x branch until everything can be ported to Drupal 9+.

Aegir 5 is a complete rewrite in development (https://gitlab.com/aegir/aegir/), but progress is slow due to insufficient funding. Get in touch if you'd like to help with this initiative.